# Formatting <datalist> HTML?

Tags: html, css

I wondered if it were possible to style `<datalist>` (example: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/be77Z/)).

I have tried inline css, such as `background-color:#F00` ([x](http://jsfiddle.net/be77Z/1/)) on one of the options, but nothing happened. Has anyone succesfully styled them before? or any tutorial links, as I can't seem to find any.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Like normal dropdowns `<datalists>` aren't very flexible for styling. You can't style them with css. Each browser handles their own styling for the `<datalist>` element.

From the Tuts+ website:

> Since wider browser support is only recent, there are predictable
>   interpretations by the vendors. Firefox and Chrome use the OS theme
>   for styling of the list options, whilst Opera will inherit certain
>   styles (color, font-family) from the input field. Other than that,
>   forget styling the datalist element with CSS.

Example with jquery:

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='input'>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arrayOfOptions = [
        "Option 1",
        "Option 2",
        "etc"
    ];

    $("#input").autocomplete({source: arrayOfOptions});
});
```

Comment: But [it **is** possible to style the placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399592/styling-placeholder-on-firefox), which is in the same category of things. How do you know that one cannot style the datalist?

Comment: It's not possible. It just isn't, but there is a way to work around this. You could do the same but with jquery. I will edit my answer with the jquery example.