# Styling part of the text in the placeholder

Tags: css, html, placeholder

I would like to modify the css style **of a part of placeholder**. Attention **not all the placeholder**.

If my placeholder is: *"Where (example: New York)"*

```
<label>Search:</label>
<textarea placeholder="Where (example: New York)" required="required">
</textarea>
```

Can i set as italic only **(example: New York)**?

For all the placeholder look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18400335/1373229)

Comment: Not possible with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to think about what the role and meaning of placeholders is. Most UI experts agree: placeholders are **not** labels. Labels (like "Search") are labels, and should be outside the text area. The placeholder is designed to be a sample input, or a format, not a label, nor instructions. To the extent that you use the placeholder in label-like fashion, that information will disappear as soon as the user starts typing.

For instance, in an input field for a phone number, the label would be "Phone Number", and the placeholder might be "212-555-1234". In your case, "Search" should be the label, and "brown fox" the placeholder. If you want to make that entire placeholder italics (but why?), you can do that easily enough with the placeholder pseudo-elements.

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote. The placeholder should **not** give instructions. It should give an **example**. "Where" is a kind of instruction. If the text area is to enter a location to search for, then the label should not be "Search", it should be "Search location" or "Search where" or something like that. Then the placeholder should be "New York".

Comment: You right, but it can be did and i think that in some case the developer can't add a complete label because there is no space for that and he wants gives more instruction even if for some user the placeholder is never displayed. Or it can be an exercise _(or a stupid hack)_

Answer (score 4):

Yes (ish)... but I wouldn't recommend it.

In *some* browsers you can use the `:before` pseudo element on the placeholder and style that separately but you'll have to make the *'Search'* prefix part of the pseudo element rather than in the actual placeholder attribute:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #ABABAB;
   font-style: italic;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #ABABAB;
   font-style: italic;
}
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #ABABAB;
   font-style: italic;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #ABABAB;
   font-style: italic;
}
/* prepend the 'Search' prefix */
::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
    content: "Search ";
    font-style: normal;  
}
:-moz-placeholder:before {
    content: "Search ";
    font-style: normal;  
}
::-moz-placeholder:before {
    content: "Search ";
    font-style: normal;  
}
:-ms-input-placeholder:before {
    content: "Search ";
    font-style: normal;  
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="(example: brown fox)" required="required"></textarea>
```

Works for me in Chrome but your mileage may vary. I've added the vendor-prefixes just in case but I've not tested it in anything else. As noted in the comments - it doesn't work in Firefox, and probably *shouldn't* work anywhere! Furthermore, it is considered bad-form to style the placeholders this way as they are not really presentational elements but just kind of helpers to inform users of what's expected.

**A better solution would be to NOT style the placeholders at all aside from giving them a font/colour to suit your theme.**

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder.

A good form will use `label`, `placeholder` and `title` in combination to clearly describe the expected input. Modern browsers will also use the `title` attribute's value in the required field dialogue when you try to submit an invalid required field. Try this example:

```html
<form>
    <label>Search:
        <input name="searchterms" 
               type="search" 
               placeholder="keyword/s" 
               required="required" 
               title="Space-separated keywords only" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't Show the word "search" in latest version of Firefox FYI

Comment: Even if this works, it's pretty basic that you should not use `::before` etc. to build user-visible strings that are part of your UI. It means part of your content is over here (template or HTML) and another part is over there (`content` properties in CSS files). It's prone to confusing people--who ask *where the h-ll is this string coming from???*. Also, it is pretty close to impossible to localize. A better answer would be, don't try to format placeholders; or, write your own placeholder logic (there are libraries that do that for you, that presumably allow HTML formatting).

Comment: Doesn't Show the word "search" in  Firefox 34

Comment: Can be used the selector ::after too. But probably with the same issues.

Comment: Can the title attribute be seen in a mobile browser?

Comment: I'm loving the way you're gradually backing away from your answer, but I have to say it's creative, albeit an ill-advised solution to a non-existent problem. +1.

Comment: @jedi Yes (on submit) in Android Chrome at least. I expect other modern standards-compliant mobile browsers present it correctly too.